# Enviar token CSRF Laravel por Node.js - Erro CSRF Token Mismatch

Tags: laravel, node.js, api, axios, csrf

Boa noite!

Tenho uma API ao qual foi desenvolvida em Laravel, e quando estou consumindo a mesma em NODE.JS com axios e está retornando o **erro CSRF Token Mismatch**

Portanto acredito que preciso enviar o Token pelo Node, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de fazer isso.

Abaixo meu código que está consumindo a API

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/messages', {
    message: 'oi, isso teste',
    id:11
},{
    
username: 'admin',
password:'admin'
    
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    console.log(res)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Ola,

Eu tenho o ambiente de trabalho com Laravel como API e front com ReactJs, de repente funcione para você.

Só colocar headers com Autorization e passar o token.

Eu fiz deste jeito...

```
useEffect(()=>{
   api.get('api/editoras', {
      headers: { 
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` 
      }
   }).then(response=>{
       if(response.data.status){
          alert('Sessão expirado');
          history.push('/');
       }
         setEditoras(response.data);
       });
},[]);
```